# How do I keep my Dell computer from freezing Windows 7 when I redock?

Tags: windows-7, laptop, dell-latitude

Whenever I hot dock my laptop, the laptop freezes. If I put it to sleep or hibernate this doesn't happen. I'm running Windows 7 on a Dell E6500. Any ideas what I can do to avoid having the lockup issue?

Answer (score 1):

There may be an option in the BIOS regarding how the system should respond upon dock/undock. This is how it is on an older Latitude I have lying around.

Answer (score 0):

One possible explanation is that your power adapter is on the blink.

Comment: What do you mean by that? I know I have no other problems with the docking station - only when I try to hot-re-dock... What kind of other problems might I see with a power adapter problem?

Comment: @Spig: Anything is possible. But to verify, can you connect/disconnect from main AC power without using the dock?

Comment: do you mean, can i plug power in and out without using the dock? Yes. I haven't tried connecting to the doc with the power cable unplugged though. Maybe that would be something to try.

Answer (score 0):

It is a known issue with many owners, no clear cause or resolution, so many things can cause this issue.

http://en.community.dell.com/support-forums/laptop/f/3518/p/19316584/19635271.aspx#19635271

All I can suggest is to update the bios to the latest version and if this does not resolve it, start disabling devices in the bios one at a time to see if the lockup stops.

Installed software and power plan settings can also cause this, not an easy problem to solve sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Control Panel → Power Options and select the "High Performance" power plan.

Comment: I'm not sure how this relates to the question.